# C# Chart, Bar not centered in X Axis

Tags: c#, charts, bar-chart

I Created chart using .NET library, here's the result

[image]

and here is the snippet of my code

```
Series series = new Series(namaChart);

foreach (var d in data)
{
  series.Points.AddXY(d.Tanggal, d.Jumlah);
}

chartPenjualan.Series.Add(series);
```

The chart that is generated as you guys can see above has blue bar that is not centered in X-Axis. It should be in 4/4/2015 and the second on is in 4/6/2015. Can someone give me an advice? Thanks

Comment: what library did you use for the graphing? What is the type for d? Is Tangal a Date type or a DateTime? I assume Jumlah is an integer quantity.

Comment: @roadrunner66 I use Forms.DataVisualization.Charting, d is from my class which has 2 properties Tanggal and Jumlah, Yes Tanggal is DateTime and Jumlah is an int

Comment: Why would it be 'centered', whatever you mean by this for a group of points?? Maybe you expect them to sit on the grid lines? They should if the `hh:mm:ss` parts of your X-Values are zero. Are they?

Comment: @TaW Yes, sit on the grid lines. Aah you are right, i modified the code so that it removes the hh:mm:ss part and now it sits on the grid, thank you!